# Onesignal Rest API - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, onesignal, emoticons

I'm using Berkayk\OneSignal to send notifications in my Laravel 7.
It works fine with plain text in message, but i have to send also any emoticon/emoji to my user.
Is it possible?

Thanks

Comment: Yes: https://onesignal.com/blog/how-to-use-emojis-push-notifications/

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by simply copying and pasting the emoticon in the PHP string, taking them from a web page for example.
I didn't use escape or other representation.
The simplest solution is always the best.